# parse a list of objects in django

Tags: python, json, django

There is a list of objects which is printed like this:

```
[<Intermediate_table: Intermediate_table object>, <Intermediate_table: Intermediate_table object>, <Intermediate_table: Intermediate_table object>, <Intermediate_table: Intermediate_table object>]
```

I want to extract the email attribute of an individual object for which I used **json.loads(queryset)**,it shows an error:**Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

```
#I also tried without json.loads: 
for i in queryset:#the list is in queryset variable
 print(i.subject)#this gives an error
```

The function(it is in the admins.py file,it gets called for a particular action at the admin page for this model):

```
def authenticate_(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    #q = queryset.email;
    #req = json.loads(str(queryset )    
    #q = req['email']
    for i in queryset:
        print(json.loads(str(i))) 
    print('asdasdadasd-->'+str(queryset))
```

Error trace:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  465.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1364.                 response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_action
  1117.             response = func(self, request, queryset)
File "/home/saurabh/Music/Project_ques10/ques10-funda/biostar/apps/quespaper/admin.py" in authenticate_
  83.         print(json.loads(str(i))) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py" in loads
  318.         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py" in decode
  343.         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py" in raw_decode
  361.             raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/quespaper/intermediate_table/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Please suggest the correct way of parsing each object.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the error. it will easy to debug when the error message is available

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Sharma96/7f1a1a5683a97322eb440caea5a6fdab

Comment: `loads(queryset)` looks wrong. Is `queryset` the list/queryset as printed in your question? Why do you think this involes json and not [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)? How does `Intermediate_table` look like?

Comment: yes,I copied from terminal,I read from other answers about json.loads

Comment: Intermediate table:https://gist.github.com/Sharma96/7415531fbe4a2e114ed82cd3b3b8b4d9

Comment: @ssharma And where's the `email` field you want to extract? Because `Intermediate_table` doesn't have one.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right,but it stil dosen't work for any present fields,by mistake I typed it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that the object that you are trying to decode is not json encodable at the first place. Types acceptable to JSON are string, number, boolean, array and dict. So if you convert this object to string and try to decode it, then python won't be able to decode it to the right object and so it raises an error.

If you really want to use JSON format, you can use it on the string representations only after encoding it first like this:

```
for i in queryset:
    print(json.loads(json.dumps(str(i))))
```

You may also need to define__str__() method for your model.

Your code without json.loads() is failing because your Intermediate_table object has no attribute email.

Comment: Your method gives the error:__str__ returned non-string (type Intermediate_table)

Comment: ah! I think the problem is with __str__ representation. Can you simply print(str(i)) and see what it prints?. If it gives an error or prints object, then you will have to define __str__() method in your class

Comment: yeah, the __str__() was the problem,though figured it out just before of your comment.thanks.you can update your answer.

Comment: the 'email' was typed by mistake.